# Add operation in queue while requesting ASIHTTPRequest or AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, ios, asihttprequest, afnetworking

I want to add operation into executing request. I read about ASINetworkQueue, but it adds all operation and run it all. but i want to add operation into running queue.

Is this possible? using ASIHTTPRequest or AFNetworking i don't mind, as long as i get what i intend to do.

## EDIT

It shows below error while i try to add another request.

> [ASINetworkQueue addOperation:]: operation is executing and cannot be enqueued'

Comment: What exactly is the issue here? Your request is currently executing or Queue is is already executing some operations? You cannot add a operation to a queue if the operation is already executing in another queue. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, My queue still executing, but I want to add another queue in the operation. is this possible? how bout in `AFNetworking`?

Comment: I am getting confused. Your operation is executing and you want to add to another queue? A queue can be executing some other operation and you can add any operation at that time.

Comment: Yes, My Operations (in Queue) is executing and i want to add another operation into queue.

Comment: So are you sure that the current operation which you are trying to add is not executing currently? If it is not executing you should be able to add to a Queue. The above error message is displayed normally when an operation is executing and then you are trying to add to some queue.

Comment: No, it is executing. that's why the error above shown. I'm looking other alternative or workaround

Comment: So is it not possible to execute it after adding to queue? Because NSOperationQueue will not allow to add an operation which is executing. I am afraid there is anything you can do on that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperationQueue/addOperation:) for `addOperation:` it is clear that you cannot add an operation which is executing into a `NSOperationQueue`.

This is what mentioned there,

*An operation object can be in at most one operation queue at a time and this method throws an NSInvalidArgumentException exception if the operation is already in another queue. Similarly, **this method throws an NSInvalidArgumentException exception if the operation is currently executing or has already finished executing.***

That is the default behavior of `NSOperationQueue`. You need to make sure that the `NSOperation` is not executing before adding to queue. There are various properties such as `isExecuting`, `isFinished` etc.. to check this.

Comment: Even if your operation is not `isExecuting` and `isFinished`, the error `operation is executing and cannot be enqueued` will be thrown if you will try to enqueue same operation in same queue twice. You must reinit the operation before enqueue it again in same queue.

Answer (score 0):

You just call `addOperation` on the request queue. In `asi` for its `ASiNetworkQueue` it shouldn't mattter if it is running or not.

Comment: hmm... i read resource says different. can't add operation that is running. you sure? i haven't try though, will give it a try tomorrow. thanks.

Comment: well, I havent tried it but from the code and the header docs it doesnt look like it wont work

Comment: of course an NSOperationQueue (ASI or AFN) is always append only though you can work with dependencies

Comment: apparently it cannot. it shows : `[ASINetworkQueue addOperation:]: operation is executing and cannot be enqueued'`